# awk - file manipulation where a pattern need to be removed

Tags: awk

I have a file with following records:

```
www.test.com
www2.test.com
www.foo.com
www3.foo.com
www.example.com
```

I need to remove 'www.' from each record where its present in the file using one-liner awk statement so that final state of the file will be:

```
test.com
www2.test.com
foo.com
www3.foo.com
example.com
```

Comment: @HadidAli, please do always add your efforts which you have put in order to solve your own problem in tiur post.

Answer (score 2):

Using GNU `awk` 4.1.0 or later:

```
awk -i inplace '{sub(/^www\./,"")} 1' file
```

Will do as you asked... "so that final state of the file will be":

```
$ cat file
test.com
www2.test.com
foo.com
www3.foo.com
example.com
$
```

Or if a one line `sed` solution is okay:

```
sed -i 's/^www\.//' file
```

Answer (score 1):

Could you please try following.

```
awk  '{sub(/^www\./,"")} 1'  Input_file
```

To save changes into Input_file itself append like `> tmp && mv tmp Input_file` in above code.